# Benchmarking with Mobile Data Connection

Tags: mobile, benchmarking

I have a benchmarking situation that requires some advise.

This is basically a scenario.
I typically use Jmeter to benchmark web page loads.

However in this case, I intend to benchmark an URL that will make some API calls. Basically I'm interested to see the response time of each API call.

The tricky part is that one of the API calls requires a mobile data connection (3G/4G) because the connection will be redirected to carriers to identify which carrier the mobile phone number belongs to. If every carrier does not recognize the mobile phone number, the API call will fail.

I did a manual benchmark(with Jmeter) by connecting my machine to a tethered mobile phone. This worked, however, I find it impractical to have a machine to wirelessly connect to a mobile phone just to run benchmarks. I cannot imagine putting a mobile phone (for every carrier) in a server room.

Does anyone have any idea or any experience in benchmarking an API that requires 3g/4g connection? Are there any tools out there?

I tried googling around, but, did not come out with anything useful.
Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: So you want to benchmark an API over 3g/4g without using 3g/4g or are you asking how you should bypass the 3g/4g restriction (either by spoofing the 3g/4g connection or writing code that will allow you to test from a non 3g/4g connection)

Comment: I'm asking how do people benchmark APIs that requires 3g/4g connection in general.